# Given vectors AB, BC, and BC Simplify the following expression.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, triangles

Given vectors  $\overrightarrow{AB},   \overrightarrow{DC},$  and $ \overrightarrow{BC}$,  simplify  $\overrightarrow{AB} − \overrightarrow{DC} + \overrightarrow{BC} $

Here's what I have done:

$\overrightarrow{AB} − \overrightarrow{DC} + \overrightarrow{BC}$

$\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{CD} + \overrightarrow{BC}$

By Triangle law, $\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{CD} = \overrightarrow{AD}$

Plugging back in we get:

$\overrightarrow{AD} + \overrightarrow{BC}$

Again using Triangle law: 
$\overrightarrow{AD} + \overrightarrow{BC} = \overrightarrow{AC}$

But, my online grader said it was wrong. 
Please help!

Comment: Triangle law tells you that you can add vectors when the head of one vector lies on the tail of the other, i.e. $\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}=\vec{AC}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement

> By Triangle law, $\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{CD} = \overrightarrow{AD}$

is not right.

We can switch the order of addition:

$$\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{CD} + \overrightarrow{BC}= \overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{BC} + \overrightarrow{CD}= \overrightarrow{AD}$$

It tells us first traveling form $A$ to $B$, then $B$ to $C$, and from $C$ to $D$ is equivalent to directly travel from $A$ to $D$.

Comment: Thanks so much, Siong! Much Appreciated.